# Tabs - Content shown after clicking one of the tab (Bootstrap)

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Well, as the title says, I am not able to display the content in the tabs.

What I am doing is I am fetching the data from MySQL table and displaying it in tabs (successfully fetched).

What I am facing the problem is when the page is done with loading, I have to click one of the tabs in order to display all the contents of the tabs.

Here's the code for the tabs:

```
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#description" data-toggle="tab">Description</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#terms" data-toggle="tab">Terms and Conditions</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#returns" data-toggle="tab">Returns and Cancellation</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" id="description">
            <p class="lead text-justify" style="margin: 10px 5px;">
                <?php echo $descrip; ?>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="terms">
            <p class="lead text-justify" style="margin: 10px 5px;">
                <?php echo $termsAndCond; ?>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="returns">
            <p class="lead text-justify" style="margin: 10px 5px;">
                <?php echo $returnsAndCan; ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The data is displayed once clicked on either of the tabs from the code above. I don't know where I have made the mistake. Kindly help me out in rectifying it.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next to setting the *Description* tab active which you did by setting `<li class="active">` you also have to set the *Description* tabs content active. I think you forgot to do this.

Add the class `active` to the first `tab-pane`, so change it from `<div class="tab-pane" id="description">` into `<div class="tab-pane active" id="description">`.

See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs for more documentation about Bootstraps tab component.

Comment: Thank you.. The thing is that I was just copy pasting from 1 page to the other and I couldn't figure out where I was making the mistake. You helped me.. Thanks once again. :)